# How does Xilinx MIG AXI interface map to DDR PHY pinout?

Tags: memory, xilinx, ddr

At the bottom of page 156 of UG586 I can understand how the User Address maps to the PHY pinout. However, I can't understand page 155 of the same manual. How does the 32-bit Microblaze address space map to PHY pinout? Let's say I use the MIG AXI interface and I map MIG to address range 0xC0000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF. Then if I read let's say address 0xC0000000, what column/row/bank/rank addresses will be sent to the PHY?

Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which release of UG586 ? Look for Figure 1-44 "Memory Address Mapping for Bank-Row-Column Mode in UI Module" and 1-45 for the correspondance between address bits and bank/row/columns. For address zero, that's easy, row=0, column=0...

Answer (score 1):

In your example, every physical address in the DDR has a linear offset of 0xC0000000 from the CPU's address space.  Apart from the offset, there is a 1-to-1 correlation between the CPU's address space and the DDR's address space.  If the CPU reads 0xC0000000, the DDR reads from 0x00000000; if the CPU reads 0xD00003F8, the DDR reads from 0x100003F8.

The exact column/row/bank address is dependent on what DDR you use and how the PHY is configured.  From the point of view of the CPU the physical layer specifics are irrelevant, it's just "RAM" as far as it's concerned.